# Using Website Information Without WebView

Tags: android, url, web

I am very new to this, and I more looking for what information I need to study to be able to accomplish this.

What I want to do is use my GUI I have built for my app, but pull the information from a website.

If I have a website that looks like this:

[image]

(full website can be seen at http://www.atmequipment.com/Error-Codes)

What would I need from the website so that if a user entered an error code here:

[image]

It would use the search from the website, and populate the error description in my app?

I know this is a huge question, I'm just looking for what is actually needed to accomplish this, and then I can start researching from there.   --  Or is it even possible?

Comment: Dang... they make it hard to post pics or links when you first start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're going to need is some kind of a web services api on the server you want to search.  Then you can post http requests to send and receive information from the server.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the permision to access internet in your manifest file. Then use the android httpclient to read the website info. You can use the link below as a start.

http://lukencode.com/2010/04/27/calling-web-services-in-android-using-httpclient/